# Why is helper file in testthat sourced twice

Tags: r, testthat

I run into trouble when using uuids in tests, as the helper file is sourced twice. Why does that happen? Is there a way to avoid second sourcing?

For a reproducible example, just create a new package, put a file called "helper-data.R" in /tests/testhat/ with th following content

```
if (!exists("test_ind")) {
  test_ind <- 1
  print(paste0("test_ind = ", test_ind))
  test_ind <- test_ind + 1
} else {
  print(paste0("test_ind = ", test_ind))
  test_ind <- test_ind + 1
}
```

and create an file "test-1.R" in /tests/testhat/ with th following empty test

```
context("test1")
test_that("test1", {
  # expect_equal(1, 1)
})
```

and you will see that test_ind is 2 in the end.
I found [this](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/1146) link but I don't see how that could solve my problem.

**Update:** Created issue on [github-testthat](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recieved a message that this is solved in the [dev-version on Github](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/689#event-1548365161).