# Why does the build of a package create a subfolder of testthat/

Tags: r, testthat, roxygen

I have a package where I need to test the creation and manipulation of a folder with testthat. Thus I wrote a test, which

- first creates the folder (using a helper-file) then
- do testing (which is fine)
- delete the folder in the end (using a test named "test-zz-cleanup.R" to make sure it is the last action in the test).

Appart from the fact that the helperfile is sourced twice (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47350561/5784831) - I found a workaround for that) I run into trouble because building the package also creates the test-folder?

This only happend, when I went to RStudio -> Tools -> Project Options -> Build Tools -> Create docs with roxygen and check "build and reload".

I have no clue, why the folder is created! Can anybody help? Of course, the folder should ne be created with the package build!

The **example package** can be found [here](https://github.com/Christoph999/test)

**Update:** Created issue on [github-testthat](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After support from [the package owners on Github](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/690#event-1548371802): roxygen uses `devtools::load_all()`, which loads test helpers. If you don't want the code in helpers to be run during devtools::load_all() you should define them in a `setup-*` file rather than a `helper-*` file.

But it seems the issue is gone using latest R/RStudio/devtools versions: now everything is running as expected without any changes suggested above!